# installation of e1000e driver on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

I am working on an INTEL NUC 5i7RYH running Ubuntu 16.04LTS. I am doing some robotics stuff and I have a Lidar connected to the NUC through Ethernet. On my Laptop it works fine but on the NUC as soon as I open a new terminal or Eclipse (for instance), looks like the application detects that the Ethernet connection is lost and tred to connect again.

After searching on the net, it looks like that it might be an issue with the Intel LAN driver.

Indeed, Ubuntu 16.04 is running the 3.2.6 while Intel released the 3.3.6 version of e1000e.

I run make install and the new version is located on:

```
/lib/modules/4.10.0-38-generic/updates/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e
```

My problem is the following, even though I do `sudo rmmod e1000e; modprobe e1000e`, I still have the old version.

And if I try:

```
sudo insmod /lib/modules/4.10.0-38-generic/updates/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko
```

It does not work:

```
sudo modprobe e1000e && dmesg | grep e100
[    0.724382] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    0.724382] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    0.741324] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    0.854000] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 0000:00:19.0 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[    0.922859] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 94:c6:91:13:22:92
[    0.922860] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    0.922889] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 11, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    0.923474] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: renamed from eth0
[  229.680214] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[  229.680216] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[  782.002381] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Down
[  817.673305] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Up 10 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[  817.673312] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[  850.739890] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Down
[ 1948.468351] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Up 10 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[ 1948.468356] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[ 1992.201620] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Down
[ 1994.445614] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[ 1994.445617] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[ 2190.835717] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Down
[ 6347.124488] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: removed PHC
[ 6347.290822] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Down
[ 6347.355692] e1000e: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[ 6347.355781] e1000e: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[ 6347.356289] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.3.6-NAPI
[ 6347.356289] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2017 Intel Corporation.
[ 6347.356461] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[ 6347.463355] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 0000:00:19.0 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[ 6347.552064] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 94:c6:91:13:22:92
[ 6347.552066] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[ 6347.552779] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 11, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[ 6347.553782] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: renamed from eth0
[ 6403.178915] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[ 6403.178918] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[ 6688.850070] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: removed PHC
[ 6688.961624] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Down
[ 6744.616799] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.3.6-NAPI
[ 6744.616801] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2017 Intel Corporation
[ 6744.617018] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[ 6744.725399] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 0000:00:19.0 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[ 6744.817569] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 94:c6:91:13:22:92
[ 6744.817571] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[ 6744.817658] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 11, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[ 6744.820301] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: renamed from eth0
[ 6746.893457] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
```

Can somebody can give me a hint here?

Best regards

Fabrice

Comment: What's the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: Hint: YOU look at the surrounding log entries, not just `|grep e100`, and YOU find the interesting ones (`e1000e: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.`, `e1000e: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel`, and YOU use a search engine.

Comment: @waltinator well, technically, as far as I can see from the log, driver gets loaded anyway, so this message per se is just a harmless warning. But if the OP doesn't use kernel-4.10 — and they still didn't post the kernel version — the driver can very well misbehave for the simple reason of changes in interface between the kernel and modules.

Comment: @Hi-angel the output of     uname - a     is the following:     Linux fabrice-vol 4.10.0-38-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 16:32:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Comment: @waltinator  well I tried to understand the problem and the current workaround consists in setting up an USB to Ethernet cable and it works fine.

Comment: I've very similar symptoms with a  I218-V (rev 05) NIC on the 4.13 kernel. Tried a bunch of things short of manually installing a new firmware. Anyone has experience with the v3.4.0.2 Intel firmware?